# Mongodb Map-Reduce job does not execute

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have a mongodb mapreduce job in a .js file and I am trying to run the incremental map-reduce every night I am doing a hierarchical map reduce from daily, weekly, monthly and yearly

but somehow the job only executes partially, so I wasn't able to debug as in the server.log I can

```
db.ABC.mapReduce(mapfuncDaily, reduceFunc, { query: { REQUEST_TIME: { $gte: date } }, out:{ reduce: "ABC_rollup_daily"} } );
db.ABC_rollup_daily.mapReduce(mapfuncMonthly, reduceFunc, { query: { '_id.ts': { $gte: date } }, out:{ reduce: "ABC_rollup_monthly"} } );
db.ABC_rollup_daily.mapReduce(mapfuncWeekly, reduceFunc, { query: { '_id.ts': { $gte: date } }, out:{ reduce: "ABC_rollup_weekly"} } );
db.ABC_rollup_monthly.mapReduce(mapfuncYearly, reduceFunc, { query: { '_id.ts': { $gte: firstDay } }, out:{ reduce: "ABC_rollup_yearly"} } );

db.XYZ.mapReduce(mapfXYZDaily, reduceFunc, { query: { LAST_UPDATED: { $gte: date } }, out:{ reduce: "XYZ_rollup_daily"} } );
db.XYZ_rollup_daily.mapReduce(mapfuncMonthly, reduceFunc, { query: { '_id.ts': { $gte: date } }, out:{ reduce: "XYZ_rollup_monthly"} } );
db.XYZ_rollup_daily.mapReduce(mapfuncWeekly, reduceFunc, { query: { '_id.ts': { $gte: date } }, out:{ reduce: "XYZ_rollup_weekly"} } );
db.XYZ_rollup_monthly.mapReduce(mapfuncYearly, reduceFunc, { query: { '_id.ts': { $gte: firstDay } }, out:{ reduce: "XYZ_rollup_yearly"} } );
```

If one of the function had a wrong spelling can the entry map-reduce job exit?
Is his correct way to execute a map-reduce job from JavaScript?

I am also defining functions, which I haven't pasted here...map and reduce

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "somehow the job only executes partially"

Comment: basically it finishes the mapreduce for ABC and does not execute for XYZ...any idea?

Comment: maybe a bug in your map and/or reduce function?

Comment: what i realized is that i had misspelled the mapper function in one of the jobs and so everything after that job would fail? is that something normal? so in map reduce running thru javascript if one job has error the entire script exits?